# YouTubePlayer api issue

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I play video in `MainActivity`and video is playig fine. While playing video, if I open the same activity another time and come back to previous `MainActivity` youtube progressbar keeps turning and nothing happens. I read the documentation and couldn't find anything related this problem. Indeed, the documentation is very old (updated in 2015), and `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi` library was updated in 2017. Guide me to right direction.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity
    implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "api_key";
private YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayer);
    youtubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    Log.w("youtube_activity", "onInitialization success");
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo("0KSOMA3QBU0");
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
}
```

layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: if you get your api key from youtube . check your video url or video name

Comment: @SARATHV video is playing fine. The problem is occured when I come back to previous activity.

Comment: have you tried your initialization code in onresume? what are you doing in onclick?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yourpage);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent); Try this one

Comment: @SARATHV I want to keep the activity in stack to be able to go back to play previous video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution with releasing `YouTubePlayer` when going to another youtubeplayeractivity. When came back to previous youtubeplayeractivity reninitialized `YouTubePlayerView`.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    youTubePlayer.release();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    youtubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
}
```